# Getting value of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list which contains 2 dictionaries as follows:

`accuracy=[{'value':1,'key':'apple'},
           {'value':2,'key':'orange'}]`

I have a code like the below:

```
for fruit in accuracy:
    print fruit
```

The above code will give the following result:

`{'value':1,'key':'apple'}
  {'value':2,'key':'orange'}`

But i want something like this:

If i give `name=fruit.key` the output should be `name=apple` and same in the case for orange also and  If i give `name=fruit.value` the output should be `value=1` and similar case for other fruit too. how can I achieve this.I know the above code i.e; `name=fruit.key` wont produce my desired result.So is there anyway to get it?please help

Comment: Any reason your `dict`'s aren't just `{'apple': 1}` and `{'orange': 2}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```py
accuracy=[{'value':1,'key':'apple'}, {'value':2,'key':'orange'}]
for fruit in accuracy:
    print 'name={key}'.format(**fruit)
    print 'value={value}'.format(**fruit)
```

I believe this meets your needs. You can read more on Python's string formatting (`str.format()` method) here:

- [Python 2.7.3 Manual: Format examples](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples)

### Using dot notation

@mgilson mentioned another possibility, which may meet your requirements more. Although I believe this is an overkill in this case (why do it just to change notation?), it may be interesting to some, so I add it below:

```py
# Here is the special class @mgilson mentioned:
class DotDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.get(attr, None)
    __setattr__=dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__=dict.__delitem__

accuracy=[{'value':1,'key':'apple'}, {'value':2,'key':'orange'}]    
for fruit in accuracy:
    # Convert dict to DotDict before passing to .format() method:
    print 'name={fruit.key}'.format(fruit=DotDict(fruit))
```

Comment: You could even use `print 'name = {fruit[key]}'.format(fruit=fruit)` which is a bit closer to OP's request if I understand it correctly.  (and if `fruit` were a `DotDict` ...)

Comment: @mgilson: Yes, or `print 'name = {[key]}'.format(fruit)`. There are many possibilities to do that.